# MarkLogic ml-gradle versions

Tags: marklogic

I need to export a project from a 4.x Data Hub. I can use mlhubExportProject command for a 5.x Data Hub,  but am unsure of the equivelent command/process for 4.x Data Hub.

( Can I also confirm which version ml-gradle plugin should be used with a combination of Gradle 5.1.1 , Data Hub 4.1.1 and openJDK 1.8.0_262? )

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that hubExportProject in DHF 5.x is just creating a zip based on the project directory - it's not exporting anything from MarkLogic. There's not an equivalent task in DHF 4.x, but you can effectively do the same thing by zipping up your project directory. I would first delete the non-version-controlled directories though, like "build" in particular.